# Outputting only the objects with "readas" false

Tags: python, class, object

Using my current setup on my code; how do i output only the False objects ("hasBeenRead = False")

```
#An SMS Simulation
SMSStore = []
unreadMessage = []

class SMSMessage(object):



    def __init__(self, messageText, fromNumber):
        self.hasBeenRead = False
        self.messageText = messageText
        self.fromNumber = fromNumber



    def markAsRead(self, hasBeenRead):
        hasBeenRead = True
    def add_sms(self):
        newMessage = (self.hasBeenRead, self.messageText, self.fromNumber)
        return SMSStore.append(newMessage)

    def get_count(self):
        return len(SMSStore)

    def get_message(self, q):

        print (SMSStore[q][1])
        self.get_hasBeenRead()

    def get_hasBeenRead(self):
        self.hasBeenRead = True

    def get_unread_messages(SMSStore):
        counter = 0

             if SMSStore[counter][0] == False:
                 print "From: " + SMSStore[counter][2]
                 print "Message: " + SMSStore[counter][1]
             counter = counter +1

    def remove(self, i):
        return SMSStore.remove(i)




#sample = SMSMessage("Hello friend!", 0742017560)




userChoice = ""

while userChoice != "quit":
    userChoice = raw_input("What would you like to do - read/send/quit?")
    if userChoice == "read":

        i = int((raw_input("Please enter which messsage number you want to read: ")))
        messageText = "null"
        fromNumber = "null"
        newObject1 = SMSMessage(messageText, fromNumber)

        newObject1.get_message(i)

        readUnread = raw_input("Would you like to read the unread messages: yes/no?")
        if readUnread == "yes":

             newObject1.get_unread_messages()

        else:
            print "All messages have been read"




    elif userChoice == "send":
      messageText = raw_input("Please type in your message: ")
      fromNumber = raw_input("Please type in the number it was sent from ")
      newObject = SMSMessage(messageText, fromNumber)
      newObject.add_sms()

      print str(newObject.get_count()) + " is now the new length of the list"

    elif userChoice == "quit":
        print "Goodbye"

    else:
        print "Oops - incorrect input"
```

As you can see i am quiet a beginner at coding but using what i have setup is it possible to only output objects from the list that have False?

Comment: "objects from the list"? What LIST??? Please don't just dump your entire program in here. Explain what the input is, what the output is, and where you got stuck!

Comment: i am adding objects to "SMStore" list     example of an object: False, "hi my name is xxxx", "0742017560"

Comment: and i want to append unread messages ( objects that contain False) to the unread message list